# Custom Report in Teamcity for artifact with a timestamped subdirectory

Tags: teamcity

I have a project that i have configured to have an artifact of this structure

```
results/testClassName-<timestamped>/js
results/testClassName-<timestamped>/style
results/testClassName-<timestamped>/index.html
```

I would like to create a custom report that point to the index.html

if i put in the directory structure as it is then for subsequent test run i would not get the index.html to display as the timestamp changes regularly.

Any help would be appreciated .....

Comment: Why have you timestamped the directory?

Comment: I didn't plan to timestamp the directory, I am using a load test tool called Gatling and it's timestamps the folders in the result directory

Comment: How are you creating your custom report?

Comment: I have created the artifact by doing result => result.zip

Comment: So I know that doing result.zip!index.html would get me the html page for the result but cos of the inner folder I have tried result.zip!**/index.html and a few other variants; they don't all work

Comment: The only thing that work is to specify the actual folder with the timestamp and that would work for subsequent test runs

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get your results out of the Timestamped directory trying using:

```
results/**/*.* => results.zip
```

Comment: That doesnt work still .... i have not manage to get rid of the timestamped folder